# VSTS - unpromote a package version from release view

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

Our projects is currently using VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) packages for sharing packages between projects. We want to adopt the [Release Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/feeds/views?view=vsts) feature to pick up packages at different stages of maturity for automated releases to different environments.

While it is pretty easy to promote a package to a specific view, I have not found a way to unpromote the package from that view. This could be needed for a couple of reasons:

1. Package was promoted by mistake.
2. Package needs to be unpromoted because of some issues found and thus needing to demote it to a lower maturity level.

I did not find a direct way of doing it via the VSTS user interface. I did find some [articles](https://roadtoalm.com/2017/01/16/programmatically-promote-your-package-quality-with-release-views-in-vsts/) of doing it via REST APIs, but looks like the [current APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/packaging/packages?view=vsts-rest-5.0) under the Feeds don't support this any more.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, there is no way to unpromoted packages in VSTS package management.

And I posted an user voice [Enable to unpromote package in VSTS package management and update REST API document](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34903249-enable-to-unpromote-package-in-vsts-package-manage), which suggests to add the feature to unpromote packages and update the REST API document. You can vote and follow up.

And the REST API to promote a NuGet package as below:

```
PATCH https://{account}.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feedId}/nuget/packages/{packageId}/versions/{packageVersion}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

application/json:

```
{
 "views": 
   { "op":"add", 
     "path":"/views/-", 
     "value":"release view" }
 }
```

**Note:**

- For `feedId` and `packageId` in request URL, you can use feed name and package name instead.
- For REST API versions, you can also use the older version like `3.0-preview.1`.

As below example to promote nuget package `ConsoleApp1` with version `1.5.0-alpha` in new feed for `pre` view, the REST API is (response with 202 Accepted state if success):

[image]

[image]

And use the PowerShell to achieve the example, and script can be:

```
$releaseViewURL = "https://marinaliu.pkgs.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/packaging/feeds/new/nuget/packages/ConsoleApp1/versions/1.5.0-alpha?api-version=5.0-preview.1"


$json = '
 {
 "views": 
 { "op":"add", 
 "path":"/views/-", 
 "value":"pre" }
 }
'
$bodyJson=$json | ConvertFrom-Json

$user="name"
$token="p1tjzehdq6tilwfjdbgbkymo3f3ojszmrlfgzh302fww6kgwnavq"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseViewURL -Headers  @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType "application/json" -Method Patch -Body $bodyJson
```

Comment: Thanks Marina! Looks like using fixed package version instead of Sem Ver is the only way we can "un-promote a package" for now.

Comment: The uservoice is gone and two submissions on this haven't gone very far :( https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/289433/how-to-unpromote-package-from-release-view.html & https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/410315/unpromote-package-version.html